# How well does SharePoint support mobile devices?

Tags: 2007, mobile

Has anyone experience of setting up MOSS 2007 to optimise for mobile devices? How can I get up to speed on support for mobile devices? What does Sharepoint offer out of the box?

(would some kind person with rep add some tags e.g. mobile iphone pda)

Comment: have a look at the response given to this similar question:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50852/what-are-the-limitations-of-mobile-device-access-in-sharepoint-2010/51049#51049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WCM features of MOSS the best way is to do with variations, OTherwise we need to go ahead with the /m version of each site. this can be customizable also

Comment: If variations are a possibility then worth looking at.  Issues around server performance when using variations though.

Comment: Variations helps better management in a structured way

Answer (score 4):

Those are all probably great options.  Here is a pure SharePoint 2007 option for you to start quick and see for yourself:

1. go to a site and let the page load
2. go up to the url and remove the 'default.aspx', replacing it with "m", then hit enter to veiw the page
   (your url should be something like: http://yourportal/sub-site/m)

This will display the default text version of the page that SharePoint generates for you.

If you investigate further, I believe there are a few options when creating lists and pages that allow you to create a more mobile friendly version.

Answer (score 3):

It might also be worth checking out a product called Mobile Entree, http://www.mobileentree.com/, which provides a rich cross device mobile interface on to SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

OOB SharePoint 2007 is not that good on mobile devices. For iPhone there are several apps or you can browse as normal.

For instance check out [iShare in the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/ishare/id305862898?mt=8).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out Tim Kremmer presentation I saw at the Sydney SharePoint Users Group. Very impressive.

April 2009, Sound Bytes
http://www.sharepointusers.org.au/Sydney/User%20Group%20Presentations/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Or Straight to the presentation....
http://www.sharepointusers.org.au/Sydney/User%20Group%20Presentations/April%202009%20Sound%20Bytes%20-%20iPhone%20Integration.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not for iPhone, but there is a BlackBerry third party solution that provides SharePoint access to 2007 and 2010: http://silverdust.softartisans.com